# Euler's proof of $\frac{\pi}{6}=1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pi, absolute-convergence

Euler proved

> $$\frac{\pi}{6}=1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\cdots$$
> where the reasoning of the signs thus is prepared, so that of the second may be had as $-$, prime numbers of the form $4m-1$ have a $-$ sign, prime numbers of the form $4m+1$ a $+$ sign, but composite numbers have that sign which agrees with the account of the multiplication from the primes.

He proved it by combining
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\prod_{p\,\text{prime},p\gt 2}\frac{1}{1-(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p^{-1}}$$
(which is a special case of the Euler product of the Dirichlet beta function)
with
$$\frac{1}{(1-az)(1-bz)(1-cz)\cdots}=1+Az+Bz^2+\cdots$$
where
$$A=\text{sum of the individual terms},$$
$$B=\text{sum of the two factors at a time},$$
etc. with the same factors not excluded, and set $z=1$.

But, there is one problem with Euler's proof. He is multiplying infinitely many geometric series and collecting like powers – treating it like polynomial multiplication, this surely requires some justification; can we prove that the factors in
$$\frac{1}{(1-az)(1-bz)(1-cz)\cdots}$$
(where $a,b,c,\ldots$ are the signed reciprocal primes) can be arbitrarily rearranged?

Euler is not very rigorous and I can't figure it out myself – how to save Euler's proof?

**Added:** GH from MO has already provided an answer on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459675/eulers-proof-of-frac-pi6-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-frac15

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150189/discussion-on-question-by-nomas2-eulers-proof-of-frac-pi61-frac12); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.